# Froala Editor Image uploaded but not showing

Tags: php, image, upload, froala

I was able to upload image using froala editor with PHP and AJAX as explained. However, I can't access the uploaded file. I went on to check through FTP client and it shows uploaded properly. Then I checked the right permission, they are 777 similar to other image files in that folder. Then I changed the name of file through FTP and tried to access, it shows correctly.

It is only that when file is uploaded, I can't access the file. I tried everything but it won't show instead the error message is 404 Not Found.

Here is how I am accessing the image file.

http://www.domainname.com/images/imagename.jpg

Error is 
Not Found

The requested URL /images/247f39.png was not found on this server.

image spelling and everything is checked.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks,

Faisal

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the image cannot be accessed at the URL specified. You can easily test that by trying to access the image in the browser http://www.domainname.com/images/247f39.png. Additionally, you can check the images folder and see where the image was actually written.

Comment: I already did this. Image exists at the very same location. it saves the name correctly and the extension as well. I downloaded the file in local folder to see if it is corrupted but it is perfectly fine.

Image is uploaded and in same location. Its just that not displaying while accessing the file. permissions are 777

Comment: How have you changed the PHP upload file? From what path are you making the request?

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure That `fileinfo` is Enabled in your PHP Configartion

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], getcwd() . "/uploads/" . $name);

$response = new StdClass;
$response->link = "http://localhost/manas/admin/uploads/" . $name;
echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
```

use absolute path, in my case it is - http://localhost/manas/admin/uploads/